# Index not showing properly in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have write a program in `java` of `Arraylist` and my code is showing below:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

list.add("aap");
list.add("Janam");
list.add("aaa");
list.add("atm");

int i = Collections.binarySearch(list,"aaa");
System.out.println(i);
```

It is showing me index no -2.I think it will show me 2.

but in case if I write `list.add("vinit");` in place of  `list.add("aaa");`
Then I will get the correct and index no 2.

So I can't understand the issue with string "aaa".

Comment: Look at the documentation for `binarySearch`, in particular where it states the preconditions. *Always* read the documentation when something doesn't behave as you expect it to. (Also, I'd strongly recommend that you stop using raw types...)

Comment: It sounds like you still haven't read the documentation for the method. Please do so.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)

Comment: @Sandesh `The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get exactly what I want by using `list.sort()` before `Collections.binarySearch(list,"aaa");`

Answer (score 0):

In order to match what you're expecting :

```
int i = list.indexOf("aaa");
```